# Method argument that could be an implementation of N interfaces

Tags: java, java-8

Is there a way in Java using generics that will allow me to specify a method argument that either implements interface A OR B?

```
public void foo(Object bar) // bar could either be an implementation of interface A or interface B but nothing else.

private interface A<T>
{
    Object work(final Fizz fizz, final T t);
}

private interface B
{
    Object work(final Fizz fizz);
}
```

Comment: Are `A` or `B` related to each other in any way?

Comment: @Makoto A and B are logically related, in that B is pretty much the same as A except it only has a fizz object in its work signature.

Comment: How does the caller of `work` know whether it should pass a `T` argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not a real solution in the general sense, but for your particular example, you could try something like:

```
public <T> void foo(A<T> bar) {
    // ...
}

private interface A<T> {
    Object work(final Fizz fizz, final T t);
}

private interface B extends A<Void> {

    default Object work(final Fizz fizz) {
        return work(fizz, null);
    }

    Object work(final Fizz fizz, final Void ignoreMe);
}
```

Comment: Note that a signature like `<T> void foo(A<T> bar)` is not better than `void foo(A<?> bar)`, in both cases, the implementation of `foo` has no idea of the actual type of `T` and can’t provide any compatible argument to the second parameter of `A.work`, other than `null`.

Answer (score 1):

No; since there's no implicit relationship between `A` and `B` except the *coincidental* implementation of a `work` method (and with different signatures to boot), your only approach is to overload the method.

```
public void foo(A<?> bar) { }

public void foo(B bar) { }
```